# Add friend Ajax then change to friend requested

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button that sends the data to the database with Ajax. But How would I make this button change to friend requested automatically once this data is sent through?

Would I put my friend requested/revoke button in the success to replace it?

Add friend button

```
<button cursor='pointer' onClick=\"addfriend(".$user2_id.");\">Add Friend</button>
```

AJAX

```
function addfriend(user2_id){   
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../add_friend.php",
   data: "user2_id="+user2_id,
   success: function(){
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: Why not just have both buttons in the HTML, and hide show whichever one is appropriate

Comment: So put my friend requested button inside the add_friend.php page instead of its original destination of profile. Then just get it through the echo and place it inside a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this with the help of a database. The target user id may be attached to this user database or table. A class echo may be made using php if matching user id is found. The button may be given a specific class using `php echo` and the button may be styled differently using `CSS`. Also you may disable AJAX request for that button (by specifying AJAX function for some active class button only).

Try this;

In your php;

```
<?php
// if request not sent: $addfunction  = 'onClick=\"addfriend(".$user2_id.");\"'; AND $addbuttonclass = "active";
// if request sent: $addbuttonclass = "inactive";
?>
```

and in your button part;

```
<button class="<?php echo $addbuttonclass; ?>" <?php echo $addfunction; ?>\">Add Friend</button>
```

Finally your CSS

```
.active{
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #0066CC;
}
.inactive{
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Comment: Could you mock up an example maybe @blasteralfred?

Comment: its time consuming. you have to design a database and logic yourself. stackoverflow wont assist you in A-Z

Comment: I already have my database structure and 99% of the code. My add friend works. Just need the button to change that is it. I'll have a go myself.

Comment: Maybe its just `if($query=1){ echo"FRIEND REQUESTED BUTTON"; }`
Then pass that data in the success.

Comment: yea if you want to echo button conditionally. Hope I helped you :)

Comment: My apologies Blasteralfred. My internet is up and down and has been most of the day, Virgin for you. ;) I will give your method a go. Thank you